# how to use jquery auto-complete to load from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

What I want to do is to be able to load data from the database which will show up as an auto-complete text below the textbox.
I'm using the ajax function in jquery to load data from the database. My problem now is how to put that data in the auto-suggest box.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/jq.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bigiframe.js"></script>              
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/otocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#example').keyup(function(){       
          var inpval = $('#example').val();       
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
            data: ({p : inpval}),
                url: 'query.php',
                success: function(data) {
                      $("#yoh").autocomplete(data);
                }
            });
         });    
      });
    </script>          
  </head>
  <body>
     text: <input id="example" />               
     <div id="yoh"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are otocomplete.js/otocomplete.css the [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) & its stylesheet? I'll assume that they are.

Is there a reason you are putting the autocomplete inside of an ajax method? It works without it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<script src="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example").autocomplete("query.php", {
            width: 260,
            selectFirst: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your php file should output one result per line, like so:

```
Gyr Falcon
Lanner Falcon
Red Falcon
...
```

This is all lifted straight from http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/ but I tested it, so I know it will work.

EDIT: I just read that the plugin's author [no longer supports it](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), and recommends using [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache). Personally, I'm not a big fan of jQuery UI, I just want the author's intent to be represented here.

EDIT 2: I didn't realize that you're trying to do some kind of custom UI for the auto suggest. Feel free to ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) to your `#example` input.

For example you can add a `.keyup()` event handler and run your code after the first `xx` characters have been entered.

Comment: @Ieyasu Sawada Does the function execute? In your code there are not even `<script>` tags around it, so that would be the first thing to check. Just add a `alert(inpval);` right after `var inpval = $('#example').val();`.

Comment: yup, the alert works, and it shows the actual text that I have inputted. I edited it for the 2nd time,and done with the corrections

Comment: @Ieyasu Sawada Well, in that case the problem lies somewhere else so you might want to add an error handler to the `.ajax` call and for example echo / alert the `data` it returns.